# Delete a key value pair with a $_POST loop

Tags: php

I have a simple issue but I am not seeing the solution. I am able to update and/or insert a key value pair. But I like to delete a key value pair if meta_shopping_value doesn't exist any more in the $_POST array.

I have a simple UI where the user can edit his order. I think I need the following logic:

```
if $check_key not in $_POST -> delete
if $_POST == $check_key  -> update
if $_POST not in $check_key  -> insert



 function update_furniture_key_value_db($params) {
    foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            //CHECK if key value pair exists UPDATE
            $check_key = $exhibitor_data->read_user_key_data($key);
            if (isset($check_key->meta_shopping_value)) {
              //echo ' UPDATE ' . $check_key->meta_shopping_value . '<br/>';
              echo $exhibitor_data->update_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
//DELETE if not 
            } else {//INSERT
                // 'INSERT query<br/>';
               echo $exhibitor_data->create_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }

    update_furniture_key_value_db($_POST);
```

I tried with this function

```
  function update_furniture_key_value_db($params) {
        foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
                //CHECK if key value pair exists UPDATE
               $check_key = $exhibitor_data->read_user_key_data($key);
        if (isset($check_key->meta_shopping_value) && ($check_key == $key)) {
           //echo $key . ' = ' . $check_key->meta_shopping_value . '<br/>';
            echo $exhibitor_data->update_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
        } elseif (isset($check_key->meta_shopping_value)) {
              echo $exhibitor_data->delete_user_key_data($key);
            //echo 'DELETE';
        } else {// INSERT
           // echo 'INSERT query<br/>';
            echo $exhibitor_data->create_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
        }
            }
        }

        update_furniture_key_value_db($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i came up with this solution not the most perfect one but i does the job for now

table structur is:

### meta_id     wp_user_id      meta_shopping_key       meta_shopping_value

1/from the $params put only the meta_shopping_key values in a tmpArrayPost
2/check if a stored key/value pair is in array tmpArrayPost (!in_array($stored_value->meta_shopping_key, $tmpArrPost))
3/if not execute a delete query

```
      $exhibitor_data = new ExhibitorData($current_user->ID);
            foreach($params as $param => $value){
                $tmpArrPost[] .= $param;
            }   
       $stored_key_values = $exhibitor_data->read_user_all_meta_data($current_user->ID);
        foreach ($stored_key_values as $key => $stored_value) {
                    //CHECK IF STORED KEY IS ALSO SELECTED IN $_POST/$params
                    if (!in_array($stored_value->meta_shopping_key, $tmpArrPost)) {
                        $exhibitor_data->delete_user_key_data($stored_value->meta_shopping_key);
                    } 
                }
//now continue
    foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
            //CHECK for UPDATE or INSERT
            $check_key = $exhibitor_data->read_user_key_data($key);
            if (isset($check_key->meta_shopping_value)) {
               //update
                echo $exhibitor_data->update_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
            } else {//ELSE INSERT
                //echo 'INSERT query<br/>';
                echo $exhibitor_data->create_user_key_data($key, $val) . '<br/>';
            }
        }
```